# How can I invoke a method if the Window size changes in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, event-handling

While I know a bit about event handlers, but not really enough about how to impement them.

So the question is: How can I call my method

```
redrawWidgets();
```

without manually checking everytime if the main window changed size?

Note that I did not use XAML and instead coded the GUI by hand, since that how I stupidally started this project. The next one I will definetly do with XAML.

My mainWindow looks as follows:

```
using AlgorithmComparer.src.View.Main;
using System.Windows;
using AlgorithmComparer.src.Model;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace AlgorithmComparer.src.View
{
    public class MainWindow : Window, IView
    {
        ControllerClass _controller;

        private AlgorithmRuntimeView _leftAlgorithmRuntimeView;
        private AlgorithmRuntimeView _rightAlgorithmRuntimeView;
        public MainWindow(ControllerClass controller, AlgorithmRuntimeView leftAlgorithmRuntimeView, AlgorithmRuntimeView rightAlgorithmRuntimeView)
        {
            this._leftAlgorithmRuntimeView = leftAlgorithmRuntimeView;
            this._rightAlgorithmRuntimeView = rightAlgorithmRuntimeView;
            this._controller = controller;
            Title = "Algorithm Comparer";
            Height = 530;
            Width = 800;
            InitLayout();
        }

        public void InitLayout()
        {
            Content = new MainView(_controller, _leftAlgorithmRuntimeView, _rightAlgorithmRuntimeView);
        }

        public int[] getWindowSize()
        {
            return (new int[2] { (int)this.ActualHeight, (int)this.ActualWidth });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a SizeChanged event: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.sizechanged?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @Niklas7 no. His focus was on the *after* the resizing, I want the method that just calls it live, or whenever it changes. Furthermore, his is not WPF

Comment: Note that the "official documentation" you've linked in your question is also WinForms, not WPF.

Comment: @Clemens Oof. Thanks for the note, I will take better care researching in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your window's constructor, you can hook up to the `SizeChanged` event:

```
SizeChanged += window_SizeChanged;
```

You'll get a handler method that you can make your call in.  Be warned:  this will fire *very rapidly* whenever the size changes, as it is changing, and for any reason it changes. It'll fire at launch as the window is first being sized, for instance.  On minimize, maximize, edge drag...everything.

Comment: My programm currently does a LOT of drawing on its own, and as far as i know it schedules all drawing missions, might this overload my system?

Comment: Quite possibly.  You should consider a reasonable throttling mechanism to try to keep from bogging down the UI with unnecessary redraws.

Comment: So I did that and I will just put a counter in my controller and only update every 50ms

Answer (score 2):

You dont need to invoce this method yourself. The Windowclass already offers you this functionallity with the SizeChanged event. You can use this bit of code to make use of it:

```
    YourWindow.SizeChanged += functionName;
    //If you are in your code behind use:
    //this.SizeChanged += functionName;

    private void functionName(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //do what you want to do if size changed 
    }
```

Comment: I changed my question and added the window, where in it should I add this?

Comment: in your constructor beneath `InitLayout();`  would be asuitable spot